# reduce space between dendrogram and color row in Seaborn Clustermap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

[image: Dendrogram example]

Hi everyone. I have two questions. First, does anyone know how to reduce the distance between the dendrogram and the color row. And then how to reduce the distance between the colour row and the actual heatmap.
Second, the bottom of the dendrogram is *really* squished and difficult to read. Does anyone know how to change the line length in the dendrogram?

Here is the code I use to create the heatmap

```
def create_heatmap(df, method, figsize, row_colors=None):
    '''df should be in the form of a cosine similarity matrix'''
    # fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

    im = sns.clustermap(df,
                        method=method,
                        metric='cosine',
                        yticklabels=True, 
                        xticklabels=True, 
                        figsize=figsize, 
                        col_colors=row_colors,
                        cbar_pos = (.829,.832,.058,.019), 
                        cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})
#                         dendrogram_ratio= 0.15)
    sns.set(font_scale=1.18)    
    # plt.tight_layout()
    return im 


im =create_heatmap(cosine, method, figsize, row_colors)
im.ax_row_dendrogram.set_visible(False)
im.cax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
im.cax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")

ax = im.ax_heatmap
ax.set_ylabel("")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a test to create something similar using the iris data set. To get a larger area for the dendogram, you can experiment with the `dendrogram_ratio`. The code below uses `(.1, .8)`. The distance above and below the color row seems to be zero in the current version (Seaborn 0.11.1).

```py
import seaborn as sns;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

species = iris.pop("species")
petal_length = iris.pop("petal_length")
petal_width = iris.pop("petal_width")
norm = plt.Normalize(petal_width.min(), petal_width.max())
cmaps = {'setosa': 'Reds', 'versicolor': 'Greens', 'virginica': 'Blues'}
row_colors = [plt.get_cmap(cmaps[sp])(norm(petal_w)) for sp, petal_w in zip(species, petal_width)]
g = sns.clustermap(iris.T,
                   figsize=(7, 5),
                   row_cluster=False,
                   dendrogram_ratio=(.1, .8),
                   col_colors=row_colors,
                   cbar_pos=(.829, .832, .158, .019),
                   cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})
plt.show()
```

[image: clustermap with large dendogram]

Answer (score 0):

`dendrogram_ratio` changes the proportion of space given to the dendrogram and heatmap on the figure, but does not alter the spacing between the dendogram and the color row.

Perhaps counterintuitively, it seems that the space between dendrogram and color row occurs when `plt.tight_layout()` is run, and does not occur when it is not.